# $Z = X + Y.$ Are $X$ and $Z$ independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables

$Z = X + Y.$ Are $X$ and $Z$ independent?

**Context**

> Let $X \sim Pois(\lambda_1)$ and $Y \sim Pois(\lambda_2)$ be independent random variables. Determine $P(X = x | X + Y = z)$.

Now, Let $Z = X + Y$. Then $Z \sim Pois(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$. So the problem is basically asking you to determine $f(x|z)$. Using conditional probability, we have

$$ f(x|z) = \frac{f_{X,Z}(x, z)}{f_Z(z)} $$

And if $X$ and $Z$ are independent, then the numerator of the above fraction is just

$$ f_{X,Z}(x, z) = f_X(x)f_Z(x) $$

So the answer to the problem would be

$$ f(x|z) = \frac{f_{X,Z}(x, z)}{f_Z(z)} =  \frac{f_X(x)f_Z(x)}{f_Z(x)} = f_X(x)$$

**Thoughts on my question**

My intuition tells me that $X$ and $Z$ are **dependent** since $Z$ is "built" using $X$. At the same time, I don't think my teacher would ask my class to find $f_{X, Z}$ with $X$ and $Z$ being dependent. Now, given that $X$ and $Z$ are indeed dependent, how can I determine $f(x|z)$?

Answer (score 3):

$Z \geq X$ This rules out the possibility of $X$ and $Z$ being independent (since they have support $(0,\infty)$).

$P(X=x|X+Y=z)=\frac {P(X=x,Y=z-x)} {P(X+Y=z)}$. Compute the numerator suing independence and write the denomninator as $\sum_{t=0}^{z} P(X=t) P(Y=z-t)$

Comment: Do you know how can I determine $f(x|z)$?

Comment: @VictorS. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Why can you treat $X$ as a constant when you just write $Y = z - x$?

Comment: @VictorS. $Y=z-x$ for all outcomes in the event of $\{X=x, Y=z-X\}$, and vice versa.